# 'if / else' construction in Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to create **if/else** construction by Reactive Cocoa.
I have the code :
[image]

In that construction called `rac_testYES` signal, but it's something strange because `if:[RACSignal return:@0]` return`NO`.
Why call `rac_testYES` method?

Comment: Can you show the code within RACSignal, the method corresponding to [RACSignal return:], What type of class is RACSignal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works as expected. 
If you change the if statement to `[RACSignal return:@1]` then `YES` will be printed.

**EDITED**

The both methods are called because they are just a parameters for `[RACSignal if:then:else:]` method.

ReactivCocoa will call subscribeNext/subscribeComplited for the provided signal according to if `if` signal return `YES` or `NO`.

So if you wan do sth for YES:

```
-(RACSignal)rac_testYES {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        //do sth
        [subscriber sendNext:@"YES"];
        [subscriber sendComplited]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but in case [RACSignal return:@0] called wrong method (rac_testYES). I want to called only one method in that case - rac_testNO without rac_testYES.

Comment: you call both methods ```ac_testNO``` and ```rac_testYES``` as they are just a parameters for ```[RACSignal if...]``` methods.

Comment: If i want to call only one method and don't use standart objective-c if/else construction. Can I somehow do that by Reactive Cocoa?